# Javascript to reshape an array into new arrays based on specific column properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, rows

Say I have an array,

```
this.list = [
  {id:1, task: 'circle',   janstartdate: '2017-01-01', febstartdate: '2017-02-01' },
  {id:2, task: 'square',   janstartdate: '2017-01-06', febstartdate: '2017-02-11' },
  {id:3, task: 'triangle', janstartdate: '2017-01-10', febstartdate: '2017-02-21' }  
]
```

Is it possible to get a new array that looks like the newlist below using Javascript?

I am not sure the code snippet below is correct; but basically, I want to regroup the original array by the "janstartdate" column, then by the "febstartdate" on the same level in the new array.

Is this possible?

Output would be:

```
newlist = [
{
 month: 
  {'january': 
   [ 
     2017-01-01: { id:1, task: 'circle'},
     2017-01-06: { id:2, task: 'square'},
     2017-01-10: { id:3, task: 'triangle'}
   ],
 month: 
  {'february': 
   [ 
     2017-02-01: { id:1, task: 'circle'},
     2017-02-11: { id:2, task: 'square'},
     2017-02-21: { id:3, task: 'triangle'}
   ],
  }
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: your second snippets is not valid I can't find the pattern you want to obtain

Comment: @CertainPerformance &@ jonatjano; I am not sure the code snippet below is correct; but basically, I want to regroup the original array by the "janstartdate" column, then by the "febstartdate" on the same level in the new array.

Is this possible?

Comment: is it possible to rename janstartDate and febstartDate or is it fixed? also can there be multiple task on the same date ?

Comment: Jan and feb startdates are fixed and each array is unique as per the "id" properties are individually unique. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```js
list = [
  {id: 1,task: 'circle',janstartdate: '2017-01-01',febstartdate: '2017-02-01'},
  {id: 2,task: 'square',janstartdate: '2017-01-06',febstartdate: '2017-02-11'},
  {id: 3,task: 'triangle',janstartdate: '2017-01-10',febstartdate: '2017-02-21'}
]

newList = {
  january: {},
  february: {}
}

list.map(item => {
  newList.january[item.janstartdate] = {
    id: item.id,
    task: item.task
  }
  newList.february[item.febstartdate] = {
    id: item.id,
    task: item.task
  }
})

console.log(newList)
```

using `january` and `february` in `list` may help reducing repetition

like this:

```js
list = [
  {id:1, task: 'circle', january: '2017-01-01', february: '2017-02-01' },
  {id:2, task: 'square', january: '2017-01-06', february: '2017-02-11' },
  {id:3, task: 'triangle', january: '2017-01-10', february: '2017-02-21' }  
]

newList = {}

months = ["january", "february"]

list.map(item => {
  for (let month of months) {
    if (!newList[month]) {
      newList[month] = {}
    }
    newList[month][item[month]] = {
      id: item.id,
      task: item.task
    }
  }
})

console.log(newList)
```

---

These works only if each data is unique, if they are not unique only the last one will be left

Comment: Super! Thank you very much :)